# crystal report subreport next page after

Tags: vb.net

4 subreports must be used within the details of the main. 
Each subreport line frame was received with OLE of Excel and the number of data that I wanted to print was limited using the next page after. 
When I saw the output, the first page was completely printed out as I wanted. 
As you can see in the next chapter, the number of restricted data excluding Excel OLE will be printed superimposed on the top of the detail. 
I just want to solve the problem of overlapping output. Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! All four subreports are in the main details. It's impossible to add details and put them in one zone.